# Code Library update on AWS Cloud Instance (PHP Lib + Laravel+MongoDB + Cron Job)

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, amazon-web-services, cron

Need to update PHP, MongoDB Library or Certificate update on AWS Linux based instance in order to run the cron job

### Here is the error from Old MongoDB Connection String from PHP Laravel

"No suitable servers found (serverSelectionTryOnce set): [TLS handshake failed: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed calling ismaster"

### Here is the error from new MongoDB Connection String from PHP Laravel

Caught exception: Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb+srv://

your help is really appreciate

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Any thoughts or comments on above issue?

Comment: Hello Guys, any one can help plsease